# Removing element from DOM

Tags: dart

I'm creating a div element and adding it to the body element and later trying to remove the element.  This abbreviated code illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
//create div
_backdropDiv = new DivElement();

//add div to body, this works as expected
window.document.query('body').elements.add(_backdropDiv);

//in some other method...
var body = window.document.query('body');

//it's odd the List<E> doesn't specify a remove method, we'll jump through some hoops...
var backdropIndex = body.elements.indexOf(_modalDiv);
body.elements.removeRange(backdropIndex, 1); //<--- NotImplementedException
```

So, the most obvious way to go about removing this element from the DOM doesn't work because removeRange isn't implemented.  Should I be going about this another way?

On an unrelated note, why isn't there a `remove()` method specified on `List<E>`?  Having to perform two operations (`indexOf()`, `removeRange()`) seems clunky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is not obvious, but deceptively simple.  The Node interface (which Element extends) has a `remove()` method which removes it from the DOM.

```
_backdropDiv.remove();
```

Ref: http://api.dartlang.org/html/Node.html#remove

Comment: It's been a while, sorry for bumping, is this method still viable, or do we have something new? - Sorry for the stupid question too, but I still have traumas from JS, learning new stuff only to realize it's junk and bad practice :\